# TYPO3 - LinkValidator ext - connect via proxy

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-extensions

I'm running Typo3 6.2. When i use the "linkvalidator" sysext, the script finds a lot of broken links which are not. The error message is :

> Exception: Unable to connect to ssl://www.youtube.com:443. Error:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not
>   known

.. for an available Youtube URL. As for Curl I have to configurate a proxy (CURLOPT_PROXY), I wonder if this issue is not the same ? Where to configurate proxy in such a case ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How did you enter the YouTube url. As for the proxy, it's propably a good idea to ask a new question for that

Comment: Hello wirap, the youtube url comes from RTE : "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxx'>click here</a>"